# How can I send data (string) from my html to my server (node or express) and execute certain function with it?

Tags: html, node.js, express, axios

I have a node.js server running and is executing what I want it to do, create an excel document with data fetched with Axios from an API, now, I want to allow a user to input a string on my HTML and then send that string to my web server, and perform an Axios request to the API that I am consuming. How can I do that? Should I use a POST request, a PUT request, or anything else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to send data from your client to the server via the request body regardless of the request method whether GET/POST/PUT.

fetch call would look like this

```js
// just a simple  get request
 fetch('/example-endpoint', {
   method: 'POST',
   body: {
     data: 'String to be sent'
   }
 });
```

And on your node express server

```js
 app.post('/example-endpoint', (req, res) => {
  const  data = req.body.data;

  // do stuff with your data here.
 })
```

GET request method is used for getting data, while POST and PUT are used for creating and updating data, so use them as you need them.

Answer (score 1):

POST request to your server, like uh `https://myserver.com/api/${userString}`
something like that